# Count unique objects that meet certain criteria

Tags: json, jq

```json
[
    {
        "user": "PersonA",
        "status": "Done",
        "date": "2021-05-10T12:38:09Z"
    },
    {
        "user": "PersonA",
        "status": "Rejected",
        "date": "2021-05-15T11:08:41Z"
    },
    {
        "user": "PersonB",
        "status": "Rejected",
        "date": "2021-05-15T15:23:49Z"
    },
    {
        "user": "PersonA",
        "status": "Rejected",
        "date": "2021-05-15T18:51:04Z"
    },
    {
        "user": "PersonC",
        "status": "Done",
        "date": "2021-05-19T14:43:12Z"
    },
    {
        "user": "PersonB",
        "status": "Done",
        "date": "2021-05-19T19:29:10Z"
    },
    {
        "user": "PersonA",
        "status": "Done",
        "date": "2021-05-22T10:40:31Z"
    }
]
```

My API call returns the above JSON in Bash (in chronological order).

The algorithm should look **for each user** having **the most recent date** which has the **status Done**.

In case the most recent entry is of status Rejected (even if there are Done statuses before it), do not count it.

For the above JSON, the algorithm should return 3.

Note: the person count is not fixed, there may be n number of persons with n number of entries.

Any clue how to achieve this in Bash using jq or any other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQ can do this alone.

```
group_by(.user) | map(select(max_by(.date) .status == "Done")) | length
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Byr81OfEP4)</sup>